# Unattended Shutdown for Smart-UPS on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, battery, apc-smart-ups

We will have two smart APC ups. Each server is a VMware server with dual power supplies. How would I configure it so that the VMware server does an unattended safe shutdown only when the ups are both on battery and have less than 20 min battery life remaining?

Thanks

Comment: What has this to do with Windows Server 2012? You want the VMware servers to act when detecting a power failure, the guest VMs will never know anything about power supplies and UPSes.

Comment: Also, details about *which* VMware product you are using would definitely help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Configure virtual machine shutdown on standalone VMware ESX and ESXi hosts protected by PowerChute.](https://www.apc.com/us/en/faqs/FA159688/) or any other of the documents provided with your APC product. This will only work if the APC power supply supports the feature of shutting down hosts/servers.